# Puppeteer timeout on WaitForTarget

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the following function that clicks a link with a "rel=_nofollow" property, awaits the new page tab open and then loads the content, but occassionally the page will not load and instead of looping to the next page, the script hangs.

How can I put a timeout in here?

```
let clickAndWaitForTarget = async (clickSelector, page, browser) => {
  const pageTarget = page.target();
  await page.click(clickSelector);
  const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(
    target => target.opener() === pageTarget
  );
  const newPage = await newTarget.page(); //get the page object
  await page.waitFor(10000); 

  return newPage;
};
```

I presume that if I can get it to timeout, I can then return false or something to check in the main code for success or failure?

```
newpage = await clickAndWaitForTarget("a.someSelector", page, browser);

if(newpage){
  var url = await newpage.url();

...
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: I'm using Puppeteer version 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

`waitForTarget` has a timeout option. The default is 30 seconds, maybe that´s a lot for you.
You could do something like this:

```js
let clickAndWaitForTarget = async (clickSelector, page, browser) => {
  const pageTarget = page.target();
  await page.click(clickSelector);
  try {
    const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(
      target => target.opener() === pageTarget,
      { timeout: 3000} /*3 seconds instead*/
    );
    const newPage = await newTarget.page(); //get the page object
    await page.waitFor(10000); 
    return newPage;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to answer. For completeness, I needed to move "return newPage;" into the try statement but apart from that it worked a treat